# How to compile a code with SSE on PowerPC?

Tags: intel-graphics, gcc, powerpc

I am trying to compile [minmap2](https://github.com/lh3/minimap2) for PowerPC.

I have this compilation line and I want to build it for PowerPC

```
c -c -g -Wall -O2 -Wc++-compat  -msse2 -DHAVE_KALLOC  ksw2_ll_sse.c -o ksw2_ll_sse.o
```

Is there away to rewrite it for PowerPC?

Comment: Rewrite it for AltiVec.

Comment: @0x90 - Yes; You need to rewrite the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there away to rewrite it for PowerPC?

SSE is group of x86 instructions. PowerPC, cannot support any code, that relies on x86 instructions.  Even if the code successfully compiled the application wouldn’t run on a PowerPC machine.

You will have to modify, any and all code, to use the PowerPC equivalent to SSE, AltiVec.  You will also have to use the equivalent PowerPC instructions, for any other x86 specific instruction that the project might be used.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rewriting it to AltiVec another option would be to use something like https://github.com/IvantheDugtrio/veclib to wrap the SSE API and map it into AltiVec.